# Using @font-face in HTML

Tags: html, css, logic, font-face

I have been, recently, getting back into code a bit and want to practice by doing a little website. So, I wanted to use @font-face to define a custom font, andI know it should be done like that (My font is called Champagne & limousines) :

```
<style>

  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines';
      src: url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.eot');
      src: url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.woff') format('woff'),
           url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.svg#Champagne & Limousines') format('svg'),
           url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');

font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;


 }
```

Though, I was wondering why we didn't have to put "src: " before each line. Could anyoen please teach me the logic behind that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for using font-face in html you should use in certain part which you want,for example,if i want use
'Vazir-Fd'(it is common font in my country),i use it like this:

```
@font-face{
font-family:'Vazir-FD',

  `src:url('/path')`
 }


body{
font-family:'Vazir-FD'
}
```

in this case i insert it in body,you can enter your font-family anywhere  you like.